# How can I redact a Django object instance based on the user's view permission?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to redact object instances based on the user's view permission.

For instance, if I have the following model

```
    class Data(models.Model):
        value = models.FloatField()
```

I would like users that have view permission, i.e. `myapp.view_data`, to see the full value, and users without view permission to only see a redacted version, say `round(value)`.

I could implement this for every view and template, but that doesn't seem very DRY and would have a risk of overlooking some occurrences. Also, I suppose in a template the mechanism might be bypassed through relation queries.

How can I implement this redaction mechanism in the model? Would this be good practice? Or is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a class method called `get_modified_value(user)`. This would basically be a wrapper for the value field.  It would take a User object as a parameter.  Based on that user's permissions, it would either return the raw value or the rounded value.

I recommend this because Models are completely unaware of context or the http request.  So no matter what, every time you want that value, you are going to need to do some sort of manipulation in the view.  It seems cleanest to me to pass user to the model method but that might have its own problems.

Comment: Thank you. By "class method" I suppose you mean a regular method of the class, not a classmethod, right? And, correct me if I'm wrong, but I would not be able to call `get_modified_value` on an object instance in a template, because it takes an argument. I would need a custom tag or filter of some sort to pass the user as argument.

Comment: Yes, I mean a method on the Data class as opposed to an @property on the Data class.  I do not mean a `@classmethod` that takes a class as a parameter.  When I've used these in the past the declaration looks like:

`def promote_user_to_boss(self, user):`

You're correct that you can't call this as a property from a template. I've never involved user permissions in a template.  I do not recommend it.  You can make a custom tag and pass it a user instance and use that in the template. But this seems like logic that should live in the controller (confusingly named "views" in django.)

Comment: If you are trying to show one type of user one thing in a template and another kind of user something else, you can either pass the correct user-based values as a data structure from the view or do if/then permission checks everywhere and show the normal value or the redacted value. 

I personally prefer the latter because it is more explicit.  You are literally saying in the template, if the user can see it, show it, otherwise don't.

Comment: It's more lines of code but it is explicit, simple, and each part of the MVC is doing what it's supposed to be doing.  But if you have tons templates to write, then checking for this in the view and passing the correct user data to the template is a little messier but would save time.

There is no way I know of for you to just ask the instance to pass different info at the model level based on user permissions.